# Explanation on data structures

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I once read the following Perl code involving iterations.

```
for my $j (0 .. $#{$dat[$Row]})
{
    $vectors{ $dat[$Row][$j] } = $j;
}
```

What does

```
$vectors{ $dat[$Row][$j] }
```

stand for?
Is that equivalent  to `$vectors->$dat[$Row][$j]` ?

Comment: Your title can be much improved - what does iteration have to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
what does $vectors{ $dat[$Row][$j] } stand for?
```

`$dat[$Row]` is a reference to an array. `$dat[$Row][$j]` is apparently an element in that array. Whatever value is contained in it, becomes a hash key in `%vectors`, which gets the value `$j`.

```
Is that equivalent $vectors->$dat[$Row][$j]
```

No, that would be referring to the variable `$vectors`, not `%vectors`.

A more readable way to write this might be:

```
my $aref = $dat[$Row];   
for my $index (keys @$aref) {
    my $key = $aref->[$index];
    $vectors{$key} = $index;
}
```

Which also exemplifies the use of `->`, to dereference a reference.

Answer (score 1):

`$vectors` is a hash, `$dat` a multidimensional array (array of references) and `$Row` and `$j` two scalars. So you're setting the key given by `$dat[$Row][$j]` in the `%vectors` hash to `$j`.

Answer (score 0):

`%vectors` is a hash.
`$vectors{$k}` is the value in the hash for key `$k`
`$dat[$Row][$j]` is an element of a 2-D array (column `$j`, row `$Row`)

So the loop is creating a hash where the key is the contents and the value is the column index.

Answer (score 0):

```
$vectors{ $dat[$Row][$j] }
```

is short for

```
$vectors{ $dat[$Row]->[$j] }
```

If you spell it out,

```
# $Row is a row index.
# $j is a column index.
# (How inconsistent!)

my $row = $dat[$Row];   # A ref to an array.
my $key = $row->[$j];   # A value from the table.
$vectors{$key}
```